# react native stacknavigator stack approach?

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-navigation

I am trying to achieve this structure:

home.js => level.js => question.js => game.js(navigate to successOrFail.js)

Now when i navigate to successorFail.js it will be on top in the navigation stack, the goal is to goback() from successOrFail.js to question.js jumping over game.js

here is an image to explain the behavior i want to achieve:

[stack navigation concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFfbv.jpg)

this.props.navigation.navigate('question') => this will add the questionScreen on top of the stack again

Comment: So ..., this is an old problem with React navigation, it is really hard to manipulate the stack, its easier to reset the stack, or go back twice.

Comment: if you had a second stack, that starts on question.js and has all of it its children, you could reset it after a successOrFail

Comment: @BrunoMazzardo i was going to look into that! thank you for reminding me, i will seperate the the stack into two stacks and reset the {question, game} stack. I think for now it is the only doable solution until maybe navigation 2.5 comes out and have an approach for that .

Comment: yeah, I hope they find a better approach to this issue